# Set different table view cell size on different iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In app I set `tableView` `cell` `height` to fix 100 pts. It looks normal in `iPhone 8 Plus`. But when I run app for example, in `iPhone 5s` or `iPhone 6` table cell looks very big in interface. How can I set cell height for different `iOS` devices?

Comment: you could search for dynamic cell size, and surly you could find an answer

Comment: @arash, I know about dynamic cell sizing. It was interesting for me, to know if it is possible to set cell height for each IPhone model seperately.

Answer (score 0):

You can set height relative to screen height or tableView height.
for example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return tableView.frame.size.height/6
}
```

Comment: Do not use `heightForRowAt` if all of the rows are the same height. Set the table view's `rowHeight`.

Comment: yeah thanks, but what is the difference between them ?

Comment: @arash, heightForRowAt is delegate method (UITableViewDelegate). bu rowHeight is property of UITableView. heightForRowAt often used for to change cell (height, content and so on) accordingly to cell's index.

Comment: @OrxanKerimli yeah I see, I meant what is differences in performance for example or any related thing

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution could be

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 100 * self.tableView.frame.size.height / HEIGHT_OF_TABLE_IN_IPHONE_8_PLUS

}
```

Here take a note of the `self.tableView.frame.size.height`, replace `HEIGHT_OF_TABLE_IN_IPHONE_8_PLUS` by that height. It will obviously give you the proportionate height according to device height.

Comment: Do not use `heightForRowAt` if all of the rows are the same height. Set the table view's `rowHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

**Note that** I would assume that it is the expected behavior for displaying the cells in different devices. You could notice that if you open contacts -for instance- on both iPhone 8 plus and iPhone 5s, you would notice that the iPhone 8 Plus displays more contacts than the smaller screen iPhone 5s.

However, if you are aiming to make the height of the cell to be proportional based on the screen height, you could achieve it by implementing [`tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview) delegate method, like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    return screenHeight / 10
}
```

means that the height of the cell would be 10% of the screen height, no matter what is the device.

Comment: Do not use screen height. Use table view height. Do not use `heightForRowAt` if all of the rows are the same height. Set the table view's `rowHeight`.

Comment: Noted. Thanks @rmaddy